# Convert a CSV to System.data.common.dbdatareader for bulk importing CSV into SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core

I am creating a simple .NET Core app which reads the CSV file and bulk inserts the rows into SQL server. I have 56 columns, So, I dont want to create an entity class. I saw a lot of examples, where they use the SqlBulkCopy but none of them are working for me due to package issues.

Can anyone help me in importing the CSV into SQL without hardcoding the column names in the code? My CSV is exactly in sync with the db table structure.

```
CSVHelper.CsvReader rdr = new CSVHelper.CsvReader(new StreamReader(new FileStream(@"/Users/selva/Downloads/test.csv", FileMode.Open)));
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(builder.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction);
bcp.BatchSize = 500;
bcp.DestinationTableName = "test_table";
bcp.NotifyAfter = 500;
bcp.SqlRowsCopied += (sender, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Written: " + e.RowsCopied.ToString());
};
bcp.WriteToServer(rdr);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "package issues"?

Comment: I don't think that the CvsReader class can be used with SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer.  SqlBulkCopy needs to either have DataRow's or a DbDataReader. CvsReader does not derive from DbDataReader.

Answer (score 0):

`CSVReader` class you are using does not implement `IDataReader`.So it cannot be used with `SQLBulkCopy` .However there is another CsvReader available on nuget  **LumenWorkCsvReader** which implements `IDataReader`

Usage would be somthing like this.(Tested below code for a small CSV file)

```
using (var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy("connectionString", SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction))
using (var rdr = new CsvReader(new StreamReader("data.csv"), false))
{
    bcp.BatchSize = 500;
    bcp.DestinationTableName = "test_table";
    bcp.NotifyAfter = 500;
    bcp.SqlRowsCopied += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Written: " + e.RowsCopied.ToString());
    };
    bcp.WriteToServer(rdr);

}
```

you have to add following using on top

```
using LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv;
```

[GitHub Page](https://github.com/phatcher/CsvReader)

**Disclaimer**: I have no affiliation with the projects mentioned above

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I am getting `Package LumenWorksCsvReader 3.9.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1`. Any idea what to do?

Comment: Sorry I did not pay attention to asp.net core tag in your question, tested it for .NET 4.5 only.You will have to find a CSV Parser compatible with .Net core

Answer (score -1):

Try converting your CSV into a `DataTable` then bulk copy as usual.

```
using (var reader = File.OpenText(@""))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
using (var tbl = new DataTable())
{
    while (csv.Read())
    {
        var row = tbl.NewRow();
        foreach(DataColumn col in tbl.Columns)
            row[col.ColumnName] = csv.GetField(col.DataType, col.ColumnName);

        tbl.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    using (var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy("my_conn", SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction))
    {
        bcp.WriteToServer(tbl);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not able to create the DataTable object since, it is expecting arguments in `netcoreapp1.1`

Comment: `'DataTable' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments`