# StackOverflow in WCF caused by R.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, r, wcf

Good Day,

i am trying to write an R code in .net to run as a WCF function. this function is suppose to import a csv file to MSSQL using R using .net code.

I am getting a stackoverflow error when i try to reference the odbc library over wcf, however if i try to run the function using debug instance it passes that point.

```
public string R_to_MSSQL_Server(string data, string Server, string Database,string Tablename)
    {
        StartupParameter rinit = new StartupParameter();
        rinit.Quiet = true;
        rinit.RHome = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.4\";
        rinit.Home = @"C:\R";
        REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
        REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance(null, true, rinit);
        StringBuilder Data = new StringBuilder();

        Data.Append(data);
        string filepath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "RTable.csv");
        //"UID= Tester;" +
        //"PWD= rstudioapi::askForPassword(\"password\"); " +
        try
        {
            UploadCSV(Data);

            filepath = PathCleaning(filepath);
            engine.Evaluate("Data <- read.csv(file<- '" + filepath + "', heade= TRUE, sep=',')");
            engine.Evaluate("Table <- data.frame(Data)");
            engine.Evaluate("connectionString <- ' " +
                            "driver={SQL Server}; " +
                            "server= "+ Server + "; " +
                            "database=" + Database + ";" +
                            "UID= Tester;" +
                            "PWD= rstudioapi::askForPassword(\"password\"); " +
                            "'");

            engine.Evaluate("library(odbc)");
            engine.Evaluate("library(healthcareai)");
            engine.Evaluate("con<- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),.connection_string=connectionString)");
            engine.Evaluate("DBI::dbwriteTable(conn=con," + Tablename + " , Table)");

            return "Completed successfully";
        }
        catch( Exception x)
        {
            return "Fail to complete" + x;
        }
    }
```

the error when i run it through WCF hits at "engine.evaluate("library(odbc)");"

This is where its being called by another machine accessing it through wcf.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainServiceClient client = new MainServiceClient();

        string tablename = "Test Table";
        string Table = "";


        string Pkey ="Name";


        Table=File.ReadAllText(@"\\lonvmfs02\Home\kr.williams\TestTable2.csv");

        string query = client.R_to_MSSQL_Server(Table, "stage04", "CWDataSets", "Tester");
```

[image]

this is the error thats being thrown inside the WCF Machine ( W3wp debugging ).

> System.StackOverflowException
>     HResult=0x800703E9
>     Source=
>     StackTrace:

this is all the exception details give.

how do it increase the size of the stack / get around this problem?

Thanks

Comment: That's a WCF service that uses R to simply insert a CSV file into SQL Server? Just use SQL Server's functionality to import the data, eg with `bcp` from the command line or the `BULK INSERT` command.

Comment: In any case, SQL Server already has a full-featured and fast ETL service, SSIS. In the time it takes R to load a large CSV SSIS would have loaded the file, transformed it on the fly and stored it in the target table. Loading everything in memory doesn't scale for large files, which is why ETL tools treat the data as a *stream* of rows that are transformed in steps

Comment: the reason i am using R is because i would not just be interacting with SQL, i would also be interacting with Postgres. Is this import tool friendly towards both ?

Comment: It can even load data from Hadoop. It's not just a tool. Apart from that, SQL Server 2016 added [native support for R](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/r/sql-server-r-services?view=sql-server-2017). You can call R scripts from SQL Server itself.

Comment: hmm .. i would look into that instead of double working myself in that case. But if i am to ever run into a stack overflow issue again in another case with WCF, is there a way to have those resource heavy functions in another thread / stack so it doesnt overflow the limited wcf stack and simply return a result ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with WCF. It's used in all web service implementations since 2008, which means that several million operations per second work without any issues. A StackOverflowException though is typically caused by a runaway recursion. How is `R_to_MSSQL_Server` called? The code may throw at `engine.Evaluate("library(odbc)");` because that's where the nesting became too deep.

Comment: In any case without the *full* exception text, as returned by `Exception.ToString()`, or a simple, standalone example that reproduces the problem, it's very hard to even understand what's going on. The full exception text contains any inner exceptions and the full call stack that caused the problem

Comment: I updated the post to show more details about the error and the way its being called.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so i looked into ssis through ssdt in visual studio. I do not think thats going to be the solution for me. What i initially want is a helper function to do different things in the background so i dont have to code it every time when building new projects.  in this case, i want this helper function to create a table in sql and insert the data. from my experience R is the best interaction with .Net that does that through code. With SSIS, for example i have to create the table first before i could even do an import. its not as seemless as importing through R.

Comment: On the contrary, both SSDT and SSMS have wizards that will create the table for you and package for you. Besides, you *have* to write the `CREATE TABLE` statement one way or another. R doesn't do that. R won't specify or convert types either, or verify types. As far as seamless goes, [a 3-4 step wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/get-started-with-this-simple-example-of-the-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017) that generates a reusable package is far better than writing a script in a language not made for ETL

Comment: To put it another way, there's a reason R or Matlab aren't used for ETL

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos fair enough. il look into it more. but I'm very curious, could i for example, build out an interface, allow a user to attach a file , accept that file, ( given its csv) and allow SSIS to insert it into a database in the background ? i dnt necessarily need to know how, i just need to know if its possible to write a asp.net/ winform app .. or even a console app and have SSIS integration in that project.

Comment: Check the first comment. You don't need anything to do that, save the data somewhere and then use SQL Server's own bulk insert tools. If you frequently work with small files though, you can use the [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/bulk-copy-operations-in-sql-server) class to insert data into a table in a manner similar to BULK Insert. You can use a class like [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/data-table/) to read the file as a DataTable or DataReader and pass that directly to SqlBulkCopy

Comment: Using CsvHelper and SqlBulkCopy is shown in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446046/convert-a-csv-to-system-data-common-dbdatareader-for-bulk-importing-csv-into-sql). The answer is a dozen lines of code. CsvReader can read from any stream, which means it can read directly from the request stream in WCF or an uploaded file in ASP.NET MVC or Web API

Comment: Thanks man. I'll give it a look and see how much it makes my life easier.